# Using the open() system call

Tags: c, file, unix

I'm writing a program that writes output to a file. If this file doesn't exist, I want to create it.

Currently, I'm using the following flags when calling open:
O_WRONLY | O_CREATE

However, when this creates the file, it doesn't give me any permissions to write to it...

How can I use open so that it creates a file if it doesn't exist, but will create it with necessary permissions when needed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You probably need the third argument. For example:

```
open('path',O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,0640);
```

Comment: I have a slight preference for @David's use of the flag constants (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSER | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH) rather than hard coded perms, but otherwise a good answer.

Comment: Yes, his answer is better. Mine is merely a quick pointer to the third argument (my string is not even valid!).

Comment: When using multiple arguments for a single parameter with the |, what is that called? "Flags" doesn't get me any results on google

Answer (score 14):

Just use the optional third argument to `open`:

```
int open(const char* pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

so like this:

```
open("blahblah", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSER | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
```

See `man open(2)`.

Comment: It's not `S_IWUSER`..its `S_IWUSR`

Comment: S_IWUSR  00200 user has write permission, please read http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Answer (score 1):

On Linux there's a third argument you can use to pass permissions. S_IWUSR should be the flag to give you write permissions, but in practice you'll probably want to use more flags than just that one (bitwise or'd together).  Check the manpage for a list of the permission flags.

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/open.html):

> O_CREAT
>
> If the file exists, this flag has no effect except as noted under O_EXCL
>   below. Otherwise, the file shall be
>   created; the user ID of the file shall
>   be set to the effective user ID of the
>   process; the group ID of the file
>   shall be set to the group ID of the
>   file's parent directory or to the
>   effective group ID of the process; **and
>   the access permission bits (see
>   ) of the file mode shall
>   be set to the value of the third
>   argument** taken as type mode_t modified
>   as follows: a bitwise AND is performed
>   on the file-mode bits and the
>   corresponding bits in the complement
>   of the process' file mode creation
>   mask. Thus, all bits in the file mode
>   whose corresponding bit in the file
>   mode creation mask is set are cleared.
>   When bits other than the file
>   permission bits are set, the effect is
>   unspecified. The third argument does
>   not affect whether the file is open
>   for reading, writing, or for both.
>   Implementations shall provide a way to
>   initialize the file's group ID to the
>   group ID of the parent directory.
>   Implementations may, but need not,
>   provide an implementation-defined way
>   to initialize the file's group ID to
>   the effective group ID of the calling
>   process.

So it seems you need to pass a third argument specifying the desired file permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Note that under POSIX (Unix, Linux, MacOS, etc) you can open and create a file with any permissions you choose, including 0 (no permission for anyone), and yet still write to the file if opened for writing.