# Open system call in unix

Tags: c, linux, unix

Open system call in unix

The following is the prototype of open system call:

```
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

pathname --> It is used to mention the path of the file like /home/mohan/a.txt

flags    --> It is used to mention on which mode the file will be open like Readonly, writeonly or readwrite.

mode     --> ?

What is use of mode and when I use the mode. Is there any example for using mode.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to check this question [Using the open system call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596306/using-the-open-system-call?rq=1)

Comment: How about reading the documentation? Type `man open` in a terminal. Failing that, type `man open` in your favourite internet search engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we can see in the [open(2) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open), the mode is used to set the access-rights of the file (as you could do with the UNIX command `chmod`).

It's useless when you're not creating the file, but when you use the flag `O_CREAT`, you have to use it.

In example : creating a file with rights 644 in read + write mode:

`int fd = open("file", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);`