# C create txt file and write to a txt file with dup2

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
int fd;

char c1[100];

printf("type text: ");
scanf("%s", c1);
printf("%s\n", c1); 

if((fd = open("test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND)) == -1)
{
    return -1;
}

dup2(fd, 1);

close(fd);
printf("%s\n", c1);
return 0;
}
```

This code works fine if "test.txt" file already exists.
But if "test.txt" file doesn't exist, this code makes "test.txt" file and seems like write successfully, but txt file is unreadable.(permission problem)

I tried
`if((fd = open("test.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND)) == -1)`
It has same problem.

I know it is permission problem but how should I fix this code?

Comment: When creating a file with `open` you have to provide a _third_ argument, the `pmode` to specify the file permissions. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Comment: I tried compiling your code and it works. On my OS (OSX) it creates the file and with the `printf` it prints the input string on it.

Comment: Note that you should *always* pass an appropriate third argument to `open()`, as @PaulOgilvie describes, when you specify the `O_CREAT` flag.  The system needs it when it does create a file, and ignores it when it does not need to create one.  You don't need to know in advance which case will apply. To the best of my knowledge, in fact, it is not harmful to pass the third argument even when you don't specify `O_CREAT`, that the argument would never be used in such cases.

Comment: Additional note: *check the return values of your function calls for error indicators*.  I am confident that if your program did so consistently, then it would *not* seem like it had written successfully in the new-file case.

Comment: Never forget to flush() before close you the stream

Comment: @wildplasser, `open()`'s docs specify two alternative signatures, one with three arguments, but also one with only two.  Or its Linux docs do.  The POSIX docs simply declare it as a varargs function.

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis: beware, `fflush` is for C streams (opened with `fopen`). Here OP uses the Posix `open` function. No `flush` exists at this level, only `fsync` which is seldom used because it is only valid for true files, and never immediately before a `close`. For streams, C standard says for `fclose`: *A successful call to the fclose function causes the stream pointed to by stream to be flushed and the associated file to be closed.*

Comment: I added third argument 0644 and it solved thank you

Comment: @SergeBallesta my bad, you are right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the open() system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596306/using-the-open-system-call)